# Mapping a returned string to a specific function

Tags: python

I have router that is deciding which function to call based upon user input (uses `ConfigParser`) and then tries to decide which function to call.

```
def SomethingElse():
    print 'hello'

def UploadDirectory():
    print 'hi'

def router(config):
    if config.has_option('job', 'Some_Task'):
        taskName = config.get('job', 'Some_Task')
        # taskName is now 'UploadDirectory'
        ###execute the UploadDirectory function
        ###execute something else if something else, etc
```

So what is the way to write this in python?  If I prebuilt a map of functions to strings, can i execute them that way?

How would you write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, building a map of strings to function names is perfectly valid:

```
task_map = {
    'upload': UploadDirectory,
    'something': SomethingElse,
}
```

And execute as:

```
task_map[task_name]()
```

Aside: try to follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the python style guide; it helps make your code more readable to all other Python programmers. Specifically in this case, prefer `underscore_separated` function names instead of `LeadingCaps`.

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky way to do it is to use `globals()`, if you're not running just by importing the `router` function:

```
globals()[taskName]()
```